# Setting Value to ngtypeahead in Model Driven Form(Reactive)

Tags: angularjs, angular2-forms, ng-bootstrap

I am using Angular Reactive form and having typeahead field via ng-bootstrap typeahead. I am having a list of states created using interface as below -

```
export interface IContactStates {
   Id: number;
   Name: string;
}
```

List of states is populated via service and typeahead is initialized in component.ts as -

```
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  text$
    .debounceTime(200)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .map(term => term === '' ? []
      : this.statesList.filter(v => 
v.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))

formatter = (x: {Name: string}) => x.Name;
```

and ngbTypahead is defined as below in html template -

```
<ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
        {{ r.Name}}
      </ng-template>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group input-group-sm"
            [ngClass]="{'has-error': displayMessage.State}">
            <label for="State">State</label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="State" 
            type="text" [ngbTypeahead]="search"
            [resultTemplate]="rt"
            [resultFormatter]="formatter"
            [inputFormatter]="formatter"            
            [editable]="false"
            placeholder="State (start typing the name and then select from list)"
            (selectItem)="selectItem($event)">
            <span class="help-block" *ngIf="displayMessage.State">
                {{displayMessage.State}}
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This works fine when I am creating new form but when I am trying to edit any already submitted form, State control value is setting undefined. I tried to get any hint on setting the typeahead value from ng-bootstrap help documents but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I make it to work. Just reinitialize the form control element again.

**Update 1**
After getting value from server for selected item, search and assign the object to my formcontrol.

```
const state = this.statesList.find(function(item){
        return item.Id === trader.State;
```

Then, patch the Typeahead control with this variable.

Comment: Would you please be so kind and update your answer how exactly you accomplished that?